# how do i print user data type variables using python/Cassandra?

Tags: python, attributeerror, cassandra-2.1

C* 2.1, Python 2.7
TYPE: 
`CREATE TYPE address (street text, zipcode int)`
TABLE: 
`CREATE TABLE myusrs (id int PRIMARY KEY, location map<text, frozen<address>>)`

```
insert into myusrs (id, addresses ) VALUES ( 0, { '123 main':98004})
```

print complete row:

```
Row(id=0, location=OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'123 main', address(street=u'98004', zipcode=None))]))
```

i want to print row.location.street and row.location.address

> Error: AttributeError: 'OrderedMapSerializedKey' object has no
>   attribute 'street'

```
session = cluster.connect()
session.set_keyspace('mykeyspace')
session.execute("CREATE TYPE address (street text, zipcode int)")
session.execute("CREATE TABLE myusrs (id int PRIMARY KEY, location map<text, frozen<address>>)")
session.execute("insert into myusrs (id, addresses ) VALUES ( 0, { '123 main':98004})")

results = session.execute("SELECT * FROM myusrs")
rows=results[0]
print rows

Row(id=0, location=OrderedMapSerializedKey([(u'123 main', address(street=u'98004', zipcode=None))]))

    print rows.location[0][1].street
```

Comment: it looks like list with one tuple which has two elements - maybe  `row.location[0][1].street`

Comment: get this error:
>>> rows=results[0]
>>> print rows.location[0][1].street
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "util.py", line 789, in cassandra.util.OrderedMap.__getitem__ (cassandra/util.c:22430)
  File "util.py", line 854, in cassandra.util.OrderedMapSerializedKey._serialize_key (cassandra/util.c:25260)
  File "cqltypes.py", line 674, in cassandra.cqltypes.UTF8Type.serialize (cassandra/cqltypes.c:12754)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: add code in question - it will be more readable.